# Store data from binary file into dynamic array of strings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binaryfiles, dynamic-arrays

I have a binary file where I store numbers as strings in this fashion: 11 43 89 101 etc

I want, by using only system commands, to read the numbers stored and store them in a string dynamic array, because i don't know how long the strings will end up being or how many. Here is the relevant code:

```
char **positions;
int all_names=0,i,j;

   fd=open(argv[2],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
        i=0;
        j=0;
        do{
            positions=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
            (*positions)[i]=(char*)malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));
            do{
                read(fd,positions[i][j],1);
            }while(positions[i][j+1]!='\0');
            i++;
        }while(i<all_names);

        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            for(j=0; positions[i][j]!='\0';j++){
                printf("%c", positions[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

All names keeps track of the amount of entries in the binary file.

When I run it I get a segmentation fault. The part where I store the numbers works fine I have checked the file. It always stores the number and a `'\0'` after it.

I get this as warning but don't know how to fix it

> warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion] read(fd,positions[i][j],1);

About `positions[i][j]`.

Thanks for any help

Edit: changed code to:

```
char **positions;
int all_names=0,i,j;

positions=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
*positions=(char*)malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));

fd=open(argv[2],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
        i=0;
        j=0;
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            positions=(char**)realloc(*positions,(all_names) * sizeof(char*));
            positions[i]=(char*)malloc((all_names+1)*sizeof(char));
            for(j=0; ;j++){
                read(fd,&positions[i][j],1);
                if (positions[i][j] == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            printf("%s\n", positions[i]);
        }
    }
```

Now I get an error on runtime:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x20400036: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   Abort trap: 6

I really think I am supposed to realloc every time cause all_names value gets updated at an earlier part of my code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be missing the important step of allocating memory to store your data.

Comment: @RamblinRose forgot to show it in the code! Edited in.

Comment: I don't understand the first `for(j` loop. You're checking the value of `positions[i][j]` before you've read anything into it.

Comment: You've only allocated memory for `positions[0]`, not enough for `all_names` strings.

Comment: The error is because you need to use `&positions[i][j]` in the call to `read()`.

Comment: If you want to print a null-terminated string, you can use `printf("%s\n", positions[i]);` instead of looping over the characters.

Comment: @Barmar am I allocating memory correctly now?

Comment: See how I do it in my answer.

Comment: You shouldn't allocate `positions` each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the null byte *after* you read, not before.

The second argument to `read()` needs to be a pointer to the array element, use `&positions[i][j]`.

You have to allocate memory for all the strings, you're just allocating one element of `positions`.

```
positions = malloc(all_names * sizeof(char*));

fd=open(argv[2],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
    positions[i] = malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));
    for(j=0; ;j++){
        read(fd,&positions[i][j],1);
        if (positions[i][j] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
    printf("%s\n", positions[i]);
}
```

You also need to set `all_names` to the actual number of strings in the file, not `0`. I'm not sure where you get that from.

Comment: I get the all_names from another part of the code it gets increased for every entry.  So that keeps changing. Should I do `positions=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));` at the beginning and then `positions = (char**)realloc(*positions, all_names * sizeof(char*));` after all_names is updated?

Comment: How does it keep changing? You need to know what it is so that the loop knows when to stop.

Comment: it changes earlier. And it makes sense that it does, cause entries keep being added in the pos file. But it changes before this loop happens.

Comment: Also I keep getting the warning this way too. Should I ignore it??

Comment: If it's set before the loop, then my code should work. I forgot to add the fix to the `read()` call.

Comment: It doesn't quite work. No longer getting a seg fault, but I get random numbers along with the expected ones and they seem messy when I think they should be printed one below the next, one in each line and thats not what happens. Then I get a great many empty lines before exiting the loop as it should.So the problem is with the contents of the array, the bin file is fine. Do I not need to realloc?

Comment: You really have a text file with each number separated by a null byte? Not a space or newline?

Comment: A binary file but yes. I can easily have them be separated by a space if that helps.

Comment: But the binary file has numbers in text format, not binary?

Comment: I open the file in a text editor so I can see it in text format

Comment: Just updated the question with the code I tried latest, if you could take a look at that

Comment: The first argument to `realloc()` should be `positions`, not `*positions`.

Comment: There's no need to use `realloc` if `all_names` is updated earlier in the code. You only need to do that if it gets updated during the loop.

Comment: Okay, but your code still doesn't work properly and I can't figure out why

Comment: Maybe you're not setting `all_names` correctly. I'm still not really convinced you have null-terminated strings in the file. It's unusual to put null terminators in a file that you open with a text editor.

Comment: Can you post a hex dump of the file?

Comment: I changed it to " " (space)