# Seg fault while trying to print data stored from binary file into dynamic array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binaryfiles, dynamic-arrays

I have a binary file that I can view as text that has words in it stored in this way: entry oneentry twoentry three (so seperate entries are consecutive but a single entry can contain two words separated by space)

I have this code:

```
        char **data;
        int start = 0;

        data = malloc(all_names * sizeof(char*));

        fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            data[i] = malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));

            int end = atoi(positions[i]);
            read(fd,&data[i],(end-start));
            start = end;
        }

        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            printf("%s\n", data[i]);
        }
```

Positions array contains the location of the start of every string, apart from the first one.

eg. if positions[0] = 9, that means the first entry had 9 characters, and the first character of the second entry is byte number 9.

I get a segmentation fault that seems to happen right after trying to print the array, but I cannot figure out if it is caused by false printing or the words not being stored correctly in the first place.

Now, I had trouble creating my pos array and asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036963/store-data-from-binary-file-into-dynamic-array-of-strings). After that being solved and this not working, I tried this version that looks more like the answer I got to my other question:

```
fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
    for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
        positions[i] =malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));
        int end = atoi(positions[i]);

            for(j=0;j<(end-start) ;j++){
                read(fd,&data[i][j],1);
            }
        data[i][j]=0;
        printf("%s\n",data[i]);
     }
```

And the same code when printing, getting the same seg fault at the same point.

I tried printing character by character:

```
start = 0;
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            int end = atoi(positions[i]);
            for(j=0;j<(end-start) ;j++){
                printf("%c",data[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

Still the same problem. Thanks for any help, and if you feel the need to vote negatively please explain why so I can improve it. If more info is needed I will provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in "Some programmer dude"'s answer, removing the & from `&data[i]` will eliminate the seg fault. I saw your comment and I think you are simply not combining the correct parts of your code.

```
        data = malloc(all_names * sizeof(char*));

        fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            data[i] = malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));

            int end = atoi(positions[i]);
            lseek(fd,0,start);
            read(fd,data[i],(end-start));
            start = end;

        }

        start = 0;
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            int end = atoi(positions[i]);
            for(j=0;j<(end-start) ;j++){
                printf("%c",data[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

This should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably the undefined behavior you get from using `&data[i]` when reading the file. Since `data[i]` is a pointer to some data, then `&data[i]` is a pointer to that pointer, and have the type `char **`.

Drop the address-of operator and use only `data[i]`.

Comment: That fixed my seg fault and it works fine for one entry but for two entries I get a blank line and below it "entry one". I ll accept the answer anyway but would you help with that if you can?

Comment: Actually I tried different entries with different length, and it turns out I get a blank line, and as many letters from the first entry as the second entry had.

Comment: @NeedHalp What are the values of `end` and `start`? Have you tried checking what `read` returns (to check for errors or end-of-file)?

Comment: start starts off as zero and then gets the value of end before it is changed. end always has the position of the last character of the entry. If you could point out how I should be checking read I d be thankful, I m just learning it and i cant find it in my textbook.

Comment: I realized start should probably become `start = end+1` but now I get another letter off when I try to print for two entries.

Comment: You do not need to edit the value of start it works fine as it is